# Detecting ACTION_UP after moving finger

Tags: java, android

Trying to get functionality for an image preview working, where holding the finger over a thumbnail displays the full image. Releasing the finger will make the full image disappear.

This was easy enough to implement, but if the user moves their finger off the ImageView before release, the ACTION_UP will not fire.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
{
    if (v.getId() == R.id.gallery_iv_pose_thumb)
    {
        // This works fine
        if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
                preview.setImageBitmap(galleryAdapter.getGalleryItemFromChildView(v).getImage());
                preview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                return true;
        }
        // This only fires if a finger is released over the initial view
        else if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
            preview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I attempted to simply listen to the ACTION_UP event for the entire layout, but this requires to have handled the ACTION_DOWN for the layout as well... which stops me from listening for the ACTION_DOWN event for the thumbnail.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you release your finger outside view which you capture event, `ACTION_UP` will not trigger

Comment: Handle that when touch is cancelled.

Comment: Thanks @mr.icetea I am aware of this, but I am wondering if a solution exists to be able to detect when a finger is lifted outside the view the original ACTION_DOWN is triggered for (See title).

Answer (score 0):

If you move outside of the bounds, ACTION_CANCEL will be called.

So this should work:

```
else if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)
```

Comment: The thing is, I wish for the preview image to disappear when the user has removed their finger off the screen (Regardless of whether it's hovering over the view or not).... Whereas with this code, it would disappear as soon as a finger is moved off the view.

Comment: @Naxin then set the touch listener on the root view. To target your whole activity, you'd use `findViewById(android.R.id.content)`.

Comment: I have considered this solution in my post. As i stated, "this requires to have handled the ACTION_DOWN for the layout as well... which stops me from listening for the ACTION_DOWN event for the thumbnail". Unless there is a solution to handle ACTION_DOWN events for multiple views in a single onTouchEvent??

Comment: @Naxin Yes it is. Check if `view` is your view, then do something otherwise invoke the super method: `super.onTouch(view, e)`.

Comment: As i have implemented a fragment as a View.OnTouchListener... There is no super method for onTouch. Should i be calling this in another context?

Comment: @Naxin okay sorry I mixed up with creating a custom class. You don't need to call the super method. Just return false if the view is not your own.

Comment: Thanks for your help user. I have tried this, but if I return false... onTouch is not fired for the second view(1st being the thumbnail and 2nd being the layout), it is just fired for the 1st view :(